# Find all values of $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\langle b_n \rangle$ converges to a positive real number.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find all values of $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\langle b_n \rangle$ converges to a positive real number when

\begin{equation}
a_k=\frac{k^2+mk}{(k+5)^2} \quad \text{ and } \quad b_n = a_1a_2a_3...a_n.
\end{equation}

So I found the general term of $b_n$ first.

$$b_n=\frac{1+m}{6^2}\frac{2(2+m)}{7^2} \ldots \frac{n(n+m)}{(n+5)^2}=\frac{n!(n+m)!5!5!}{(n+5)!(n+5)!}=\frac{n!(n+m)!5!5!}{m!(n+5)!(n+5)!}$$

So, basically I need to find the limit of $\frac{n!(n+m)!}{(n+5)!(n+5)!}$ that is not equal to $0$ or infinity.

Therefore, the limit of $\frac{n!(n+m)!}{(n+5)!(n+5)!}$ can only be $1$ when $m=10$ was my thought.

Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: Hi! I can't say if your passages are correct right know, since I should repeat your calculations to be sure, but I can say what I would do: I would try to complete the square at the numerator of $a_k$, so that you get $b_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{(m-10)k-25}{(k+5)^2}\right)$ and then take logarithm, so that $\log(b_n)=\sum_k\log\left(1+\frac{(m-10)k-25}{(k+5)^2}\right)$ and the series converges if and only if $m-10=0$, since $\log(\varepsilon_k)\sim \varepsilon_k$.

Comment: Minor typo in your equation for $b_n$, the middle equality shouldn't be there.

Comment: What do you mean the middle equality shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gamma function has the asymptotic
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n) n^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}=1
$$
So we have
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+6)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(n+m+1)}{\Gamma(n+6)}
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1) \cdot n^{5}}{\Gamma(n+6)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(n+m+1)}{\Gamma(n+6)\cdot n^{m-5}}= \begin{cases}
\infty,&m<10\\
1,&m=10\\
0,&m>10
\end{cases}
$$